# Checkpoint regex

Tags: regex, expression, checkpoint, regula

I found these two expressions in documentation:

To match subdomains of mydomain.com: `(^|.*\.)mydomain\.com`

To match domain and subdomains of mydomain.com: `(^|.*\.)*mydomain\.com`

I can't understand why those expressions mean what they say they mean. Can anybody explain both expressions please?

Answer (score 0):

Fist it is not a good regex expressions (it except other things that it should not) but i will explain the `(^|.*\.)mydomain\.com` (you will figure out the second)

- **between the parenthesis** :

`^` matches the starting position of the line

`|` acts like a Boolean OR ,between the expression before and the expression after the operator

`.`matches any character except line breaks

`*`Matches the preceding element zero or more times

`\.`matches a dot `.` character

For more information you could read [wiki doc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) and use [a great Regex tool](http://regexr.com/)